# Attributing multidimensional KDTree output in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have created multidimensional arrays with KDTree from finding up to 100 B points within 5 cm of a set of A points.

I'm left with up to 100 values for each row of my array. For example:

```
0 0.1 0.5 nan nan nan nan nan
1 0.4 0.2 0.1 2.0 6.0 0.2 0.2
2 0.3 nan 0.3 nan nan nan nan
3 0.2 0.5 0.6 5.0 nan nan nan
```

I want to essentially flatten all of the array values to have one big column of values, but I want to associate an attribute column I have with all the values in each row:

```
0 0.1 0.5 nan nan nan nan nan A
1 0.4 0.2 0.1 2.0 6.0 0.2 0.2 B
2 0.3 nan 0.3 nan nan nan nan A
3 0.2 0.5 0.6 5.0 nan nan nan C
```

So, I want to end up with something like this in pandas:

```
0.1 A
0.5 A
nan A
nan A
nan A
0.4 B
0.2 B
0.1 B
2.0 B
6.0 B
0.2 B
0.2 B
0.3 A
nan A
0.3 A
nan A
nan A
nan A
nan A
0.2 C
0.5 C
0.6 C
5.0 C
nan C
nan C
nan C
```

What is the fastest way to do this?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work - you'll have to figure out how to handle column naming at the end. Not sure if you want to keep nan values, you'd have to replace them first, they get lost in the stacking.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan,'A'],[5,np.nan,np.nan,'B']], columns = ['col1','col2','col3','feature'])
df = df.reset_index().set_index(['index','feature'])
df = df.stack().to_frame().reset_index().drop(['index','level_2'],axis = 1)
print df



feature    0
0       A  1.0
1       A  2.0
2       B  5.0
```

Comment: Okay so I used df.stack() and it worked well. I still have an Index column (which is fine) and a 0 column with all the values. But the 0 column still contains the attribute column. So the column is ### 'attribute' ###, and I need to separate those attributes out in a second column.

Comment: Did you copy the code as I have it? in the example I have above you have an index (which you will always have), the "feature" column, and a "0" column, which are your values. Not sure what you're struggling with - can you post the code you're running and the result you're getting?